# How do I fix this error message: xhr.js:178 GET http://localhost:8080/jpa/users/undefined/accounts/undefined?

Tags: java, mysql, node.js, reactjs

My app is in React, Node, Java, and uses a mySQL db.  The username & password are posted & retrieved from the db using node.  Accounts are supposed to be retrieved from the db using Java.  I'm needing assistance in trying to resolve this error: xhr.js:178 GET http://localhost:8080/jpa/users/undefined/accounts/undefined.

Here is a portion of my login component:

```
 const [username, setUsername] = useState("");
 const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
 const [loginStatus, setLoginStatus] = useState("");
 const history = useHistory();

 const loginClicked = () => {
 Axios.post("http://localhost:3000/login", {
   username: username,
   password: password,
  }).then((response) => {
  if (response.data.message) {
    setLoginStatus(response.data.message)
    console.log(response.data.message)
  } else {
    setLoginStatus(response.data[0].username)
    AuthenticationService.registerSuccessfulLogin(
      setUsername({ username }),
      setPassword({ password })
    );
     history.push(`/welcome/${username}`);
    console.log(response.data[0].username)
   }
   });
  };
```

Here is my api code in React:

```
 import axios from "axios";
 import { JPA_API_URL } from "../Constants";

 class AccountDataService {
   retrieveAllAccounts(name) {
     return axios.get(`${JPA_API_URL}/users/${name}/accounts`);
   }

   retrieveAccount(name, id) {
     return axios.get(`${JPA_API_URL}/users/${name}/accounts/${id}`);
   }

   deleteAccount(name, id) {
     return axios.delete(`${JPA_API_URL}/users/${name}/accounts/${id}`);
   }

   updateAccount(name, id, account) {
     return axios.put(`${JPA_API_URL}/users/${name}/accounts/${id}`, account);
   }

   createAccount(name, account) {
     return axios.post(`${JPA_API_URL}/users/${name}/accounts/`, account);
   }
 }

 export default new AccountDataService();
```

Constants.js:

```
 export const API_URL = "http://localhost:8080";
 export const JPA_API_URL = `${API_URL}/jpa`
```

Here is where AccountDataService is called & used:

```
 import React, { Component } from "react";
 import moment from "moment";
 import { Formik, Form, Field, ErrorMessage } from "formik";
 import AccountDataService from "../../api/AccountDataService.js";
 import AuthenticationService from 
 "../../components/authentication/AuthenticationService.js";

 class Accounts extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
     super(props);
   this.state = {
      id: this.props.match.params.id,
      accountName: "",
      deposits: "",
      asOfDate: moment.utc(new Date()).format("YYYY-MM-DD"),
   };
     this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
     this.validate = this.validate.bind(this);
   }

   componentDidMount() {
     if (this.state.id === -1) {
       return;
     }
     let username = AuthenticationService.getLoggedInUserName();
     AccountDataService.retrieveAccount(username, this.state.id).then(
      (response) =>
    this.setState({
      accountName: response.data.accountName,
      deposits: response.data.deposits,
      asOfDate: moment.utc(response.data.asOfDate).format("YYYY-MM-DD"),
      })
    );
   }

   validate(values) {
   let errors = {};

   if (!values.accountName) {
    errors.accountName = "Enter an account name";
   } else if (values.accountName.length < 3) {
    errors.accountName = "Account name must be at least 3 characters";
   }

   if (!values.deposits) {
     errors.deposits = "Enter a balance";
   }

   if (!moment(values.asOfDate).isValid()) {
     errors.asOfDate = "Select a date";
   }

   return errors;
   }

   onSubmit(values) {
    let username = AuthenticationService.getLoggedInUserName();

    let account = {
    id: this.state.id,
    accountName: values.accountName,
    deposits: values.deposits,
    asOfDate: values.asOfDate,
    };

   if (this.state.id === -1) {
   AccountDataService.createAccount(username, account).then(() =>
    this.props.history.push("/accounts")
   );
   } else {
    AccountDataService.updateAccount(
      username,
      this.state.id,
      account
     ).then(() => this.props.history.push("/accounts"));
   }

   console.log(values);
  }

   render() {
   let { accountName, deposits, asOfDate } = this.state;

    return (
    <div>
    <h1>Account Updates/Additions</h1>
    <div className="container">
      <Formik
        initialValues={{ accountName, deposits, asOfDate }}
        onSubmit={this.onSubmit}
        validateOnChange={false}
        validateOnBlur={false}
        validate={this.validate}
        enableReinitialize={true}
      >
        {(props) => (
          <Form>
            <ErrorMessage
              name="accountName"
              component="div"
              className="alert alert-danger"
            />
            <ErrorMessage
              name="balance"
              component="div"
              className="alert alert-danger"
            />
            <ErrorMessage
              name="asOfDate"
              component="div"
              className="alert alert-danger"
            />

            <fieldset className="form-group">
              <label>Account Name</label>
              <Field
                className="form-control"
                type="text"
                name="accountName"
              />
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset className="form-group">
              <label>Balance</label>
              <Field
                className="form-control"
                type="number"
                name="deposits"
              />
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset className="form-group">
              <label>As of</label>
              <Field className="form-control" type="date" name="asOfDate" />
            </fieldset>
            <button className="btn btn-success" type="submit">
              Save
            </button>
          </Form>
        )}
      </Formik>
    </div>
  </div>
  );
  }
 }

 export default Accounts;
```

Here is another file that imports AccountDataService:

```
 import React, { Component } from "react";
 import moment from "moment";
 import CurrencyFormat from "react-currency-format";
 import AccountDataService from "../../api/AccountDataService";
 import AuthenticationService from 
 "../../components/authentication/AuthenticationService.js";
 import "./Accounts.css";
 import Cube from "./Cube.jsx";

 class AccountsBalanceList extends Component {
   constructor(props) {
   console.log("constructor");
   super(props);
   this.state = {
   accounts: [],
   message: null,
   };
   this.deleteAccountClicked = this.deleteAccountClicked.bind(this);
   this.updateAccountClicked = this.updateAccountClicked.bind(this);
   this.addAccountClicked = this.addAccountClicked.bind(this);
   this.refreshAccounts = this.refreshAccounts.bind(this);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
  console.log("componentWillUnmount");
  }

  shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
   console.log("shouldComponentUpdate");
   console.log(nextProps);
    console.log(nextState);
   return true;
  }

  componentDidMount() {
  console.log("componentDidMount");
  this.refreshAccounts();
  console.log(this.state);
  }

  refreshAccounts() {
  let username = AuthenticationService.getLoggedInUserName();
  AccountDataService.retrieveAllAccounts(username).then((response) => {
  this.setState({ accounts: response.data });
  });
  }

  deleteAccountClicked(id) {
  let username = AuthenticationService.getLoggedInUserName();
  AccountDataService.deleteAccount(username, id).then((response) => {
  this.setState({
    message: `Deletion of account ${id} was successful`,
  });
  this.refreshAccounts();
  });
  }

  addAccountClicked() {
  this.props.history.push(`/accounts/-1`);
  }

  updateAccountClicked(id) {
  console.log("update " + id);
  this.props.history.push(`/accounts/${id}`);
  }

  render() {
  console.log("render");
  return (
  <>
    <Cube />
    <div style={{textAlign: "center"}}>
      <h1>Accounts and their Current Balances</h1>
      {this.state.message && (
        <div class="alert alert-success">{this.state.message}</div>
      )}
      <div className="container">
        <table className="table table-bordered table-hover">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Account Name</th>
              <th>Balance</th>
              <th>As of</th>
              <th>Update</th>
              <th>Delete</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {this.state.accounts.map((account) => (
              <tr key={account.id}>
                <td>{account.accountName}</td>
                <td>
                  <CurrencyFormat
                    value={Math.abs(
                      account.deposits - account.withdrawals
                    ).toFixed(2)}
                    displayType={"text"}
                    thousandSeparator={true}
                    prefix={"$"}
                  />
                </td>
                <td>
                  {moment.utc(account.asOfDate).format("MMM-DD-YYYY")}
                </td>
                <td>
                  <button
                    className="btn btn-success"
                    onClick={() => this.updateAccountClicked(account.id)}
                  >
                    Update
                  </button>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <button
                    className="btn btn-warning"
                    onClick={() => this.deleteAccountClicked(account.id)}
                  >
                    Delete
                  </button>
                </td>
              </tr>
            ))}
          </tbody>
        </table>
        <div className="row">
          <button
            className="btn btn-success"
            onClick={this.addAccountClicked}
          >
            Add
          </button>
        </div>
        <br />
      </div>
    </div>
    </>
    );
    }
    }
  export default AccountsBalanceList;
```

Here is my AccountJpaResource file in Java:

```
 @RestController
 @CrossOrigin(origins = "*", allowedHeaders = "*")
 public class AccountJpaResource {

 @Autowired
 private AccountService accountService;

 @Autowired
 private AccountJpaRepository accountJpaRepository;

 @GetMapping("/jpa/users/{username}/accounts")
 public List<Account> getAllAccounts(@PathVariable String username) {
    return accountJpaRepository.findByUsername(username);
 }

 @GetMapping("/jpa/users/{username}/accounts/{id}")
 public Account getAccount(@PathVariable String username, @PathVariable long id) {
    return accountJpaRepository.findById(id).get();
 }

  // DELETE /users/{username}/accounts/{id}
 @DeleteMapping("/jpa/users/{username}/accounts/{id}")
 public ResponseEntity<Void> deleteAccount(@PathVariable String username, @PathVariable long id) {

    accountJpaRepository.deleteById(id);

        return ResponseEntity.noContent().build();
 }

 //Edit/Update an Account
    //PUT /users/{username}/accounts/{id}
    @PutMapping("/jpa/users/{username}/accounts/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Account> updateAccount(
            @PathVariable String username,
            @PathVariable long id, @RequestBody Account account){
        
        account.setUsername(username);
        
        Account accountUpdated = accountJpaRepository.save(account);
        
        return new ResponseEntity<Account>(account, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
        
  @PostMapping("/jpa/users/{username}/accounts")
  public ResponseEntity<Void> createAccount(
        @PathVariable String username, @RequestBody Account account){
    
    account.setUsername(username);
    
    Account createdAccount = accountJpaRepository.save(account);
    URI uri = ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentRequest()
            .path("/{id}").buildAndExpand(createdAccount.getId()).toUri();
    
    return ResponseEntity.created(uri).build();
    }   
  }
```

Comment: Whatever is calling `retrieveAccount` is not passing `name` and `id`

Comment: yes, but I'm not sure of 'how' to get it to pass in. what do you suggest?

Comment: It's frankly hard to suggest anything without seeing where it's called from. You're only showing a small part of your React code and your Java backend, which is probably irrelevant to this problem. Show where you import the `AccountDataService` class and how you use it.

Comment: I have added in the file that imports AccountDataService which shows how it is used

Comment: So clearly this is undefined `this.props.match.params.id`. Need to check the component from where you render `Accounts` (i.e. `<Accounts .../>`). I would also put `console.log(username)` right below: `let username = AuthenticationService.getLoggedInUserName();`

Comment: i've added in the component where i would be rendering Accounts.  and the console log didn't show a username

Comment: i know what the problem is:  the username is not being carried over to the authentication service, which in turn doesn't allow for the accounts to display.  i can't figure out why tho

Comment: This makes sense, but it's too hard to figure out what's happening without looking at your entire app. You will need to narrow down your question a little bit and repost as a different question it seems.